# Is it possibly to keep money purely online?

Tags: banking, online-banking

Is it possible to keep money purely online? An account of some sort that functions like a bank but doesn't require physical receipts,cards,papers,etc?

I would consider cryptocurrencies, but not everyone supports them. It would be nice to have a place to keep the money generated from online activities completely separate from my day-to-day activities.

Comment: How is this different from a bank? One of the two banks I deal with (ING Direct), I have no bank card, can do all my 'paper'work online including tax receipts, and have never had to go to a physical location.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton - what happens when you bill pay somebody that isn't in their electronic system?  (Like my municipal water board?) Do they mail a paper check?  Would that disqualify them?  Am I being too literal?  You and JRVazquez think I am =)

Comment: I wouldn't use this for paying regular bills, I'd have a regular account for that. I'd use this for crypto exchanges, sending money to games and people online for virtual products(digital art, video games,etc)

Comment: @ZCoder: Based on the comments on your question and answer, I think you need to clarify exactly what services you require to be "all online".  For instance, it's not clear whether you would be okay with a traditional bank that has online services, but also happens to offer in-person/mail services, that you personally don't need and won't use.  Does it need to be *all* online, or do you just have a certain set of things you want to be able to do online?

Comment: What prevents you from creating a separate bank account just for your online activities?

Comment: I'll probably end up doing that if what I'm looking for doesn't exist.

Comment: @ZCoder frankly, I'm not sure I understand what it is that you're looking for...

Answer (score 3):

Technically yes; practically no.  You will be limited in the types of activity you can accomplish.

I do much of my daily banking and retirement activity online only.  But I still have to keep a local credit union account because there are just too many times in a year when I need to visit a branch.

- Large cash deposits or cash withdrawals
- Bank services like money orders or notary public
- Screwy scenarios where you need a person to make a decision.  (Being face to face is important.)  My neighbor wrote me a check and was sloppy on the amount line.  It was rightfully rejected by online deposit, but a cashier was able to verify me and make sense of the check were a computer couldn't.

All of my online banks can receive and send money electronically, but will fall back to paper.  For example, my simple.com account (which is in beta) couldn't transfer funds between banks for free*, so I used their "electronic bill pay" to send myself a check to deposit into another account.  They mailed me a paper check.  When my ATM card didn't activate with them, I called and spoke to a person.

And when some situation comes up that you do need to speak with a human, even if that is only once every couple of years, then you will realize that online **only** just isn't a reality yet.

But it sounds like it would be a secondary bank for you.  You can probably accomplish what you want.  Cut up the ATM card they send and rely on bill pay, money transfers and electronic deposits.  You will still have a back up.

Comment: *Simple can now transfer money between bank accounts for free, eliminating another paper check reason.

Comment: +1 very well said. I keep my life 99.9% online and have no problems, direct deposits, online statements, money transfers between banks, online payments, debit cards, credit cards, and even those I need to send a check to, just use billpay (I haven't used a check in 15 years) but hey I still need rolls of quarters for laundry ;) nice to have a branch.

Answer (score 0):

Rather biased answer, since this is based on my personal experience - very much yes, more and more banks are trying to convert everything online. I won't name the banks, but this trend started already many years ago when one bank started the trend without offices - all you needed physically was to present your ID and sign the documents when opening the account and they had "kiosks" around the country doing just this. And now they offer a purely virtual debit card that does not even exist physically.

Recently, another bank started an account that is explicitly online only, you even *have to* create the account online (installing their application, filling the online form and photographing your ID and moving face) and the only physical interaction is when you ask for a physical debit/ATM card (which is not obligatory).
You *can* do things physically if you insist, but they incur hefty fees (and unless you run into unusual situations, you do not have to).

Money transfers within the EU are free, as well as the card payments (online or offline) and direct debit - this covers something like 99.9% of all the transactions you'd ever need.

(location: Slovakia, but much of the EU is similar)

Answer (score -1):

Paypal is a popular option. You can use a Paypal account to receive payments, make payments to other Paypal users, buy stuff from businesses who support Paypal as a payment option and you can transfer funds to your regular bank account.

However, be aware of [the controversies surrounding PayPal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PayPal#Criticism_and_controversies). There are several cases where they froze accounts for no clear reason and then took a really long time to get in contact with the account owner. And in some cases [they allegedly kept money from frozen accounts for themselves](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2022/01/paypal-stole-users-money-after-freezing-seizing-funds-lawsuit-alleges/).

So it's probably not a good idea to rely too much on PayPal as your only means to access cash or to park too many funds there.

Answer (score -6):

Cryptocurrencies like [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.org) accomplish what you're asking. They're even better than an e-bank (like Simple.com) because cryptocurrencies are [decentralized](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/69104/4334), so there's no central point of failure.

Your objection that "not everyone supports" cryptocurrencies is true, but there are several [exchanges](https://bitcoin.org/en/exchanges) to and from fiat. (Most exchanges are online-only.)